# Difference between normally loaded website and the same website loaded within an iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm a little in trouble with the problem in object and I hope that someone of you can help me.

I'm trying to open a website within an iFrame tab, which is inside a modal form.

Following the code in object:

```
<lazy-content-loader show="vm.SiteVisibility" keep-alive="false">
    <div class="modal fade" id="siteViewer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
         bs-modal
         bs-modal-show="vm.SiteVisibility">
        <div id="viewerForm" class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Jira</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body" style="width:100%; height:95%; margin: 0px">
                    <iframe src="{{ vm.URL }}" style="width:100%; height:90%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</lazy-content-loader>
```

Where the vm.URL is the variable, managed in my AngularJS controller.

The code above seems to work, but by loading the same URL in a browser, I notice that when it's loaded by my application some parts of the site are missing ( such as the header bar or some panel on the right ).

In order to solve this problem I tried to substitute the iFrame tag with the object or the div one, but I got any kind of result.

Have you got any suggestion ??

Thanks in advance

Deby

Comment: Probably the site you use in your iframe has some @media in css and  hides some elements on some window.width breakpoints. Could you provide a the URL you use for iframe?

Comment: The URL I use is related on an internal business server... I cannot provide it! :(